# In "small" American movies

Tags: word-choice, word-request

> She's had a number of roles in **small** American movies.

To my surprise "In small American movies" only had 2 hits on Google. The same with "In smaller American movies". So my question is, is "small" not a natural choice of adjective here? Is another one prefered? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps "in minor Hollywood movies".

Comment: ...or in [B movies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_movie).

Comment: You also hear "indie movies" used to mean movies produced by a small movie studio ("indie" is short for "independent" and it means "independent of any of the very large studios").

Comment: in minor American movies. Not all American movies are Hollywood movies. Anyway, small is OK, because big American movies sounds ok to me.

Comment: *Indie* is the better word here for indie films; *minor* refers to the impact upon the history of film or how important the film is/was; *low-budget*, or *B-movie* refers to the size of the budget used for the movie. As you can tell, you need to be pretty specific.

Answer (score 1):

Basically when they use "small" as an adjective for a movie. It refers to the budget, they spend on making it. So in that regard a "low-budget movie" is a better choice for conveying the same notion. Also as you mentioned it "small movie" is not quite common and it is better to be used in a informal context.

Comment: Mike, you need to take more care with the punctuation of your answers. It is not only the content that matters. As it stands, your answer needs both a capital letter at the start of the third sentence and several commas as well as a couple of corrections.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I need to pay more attention. Thank You!